# Fit minted environment to textwidth

Tags: minted, resize, textwidth

I can't get minted environments to fit into linewidth:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{listing}
\begin{minted}{python}
from foo import Foo, Fuzz, Whizz, Buzz, Bar, Baz, Fee, Fie, Foe, Foo, Foobar, WhizzBuzz, LongBar, FieFoe, FeeFie, FooFuzz
a = Foo()
b = Bar()
c = a + b
print(c)
\end{minted}
\caption{Code example}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

I tried `minipages`, `resizebox`, `scalebox` and playing on fontsizes.

With minipages the `{\linewidth}` is ignored and the longest line goes over the limit; with `resizebox/scalebox` I get errors; with fontsizes the first line still won't fit even with `\tiny`.

I guess there is some weird interaction going on between minted and other environments?

Comment: When I add [frame=single] the frame does fit into \textwidth but not the code that is longer.

Comment: If you showed an example of what you tried it would be easier to answer. `minipage`does not have a `[\linewidth]` option so what is ignored? If you got an error with`resizebox`  presumably you got the syntax  wrong but hard to guess. As with all verbatim environments you can not use `minted` in the argument of another command. I would not scale though just choose a smaller font such as `\small`

Comment: As described in the comment I used tiny as a fontsize but it is not enough. Minipage does allow a \textwidth argument by writing \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}. Resizebox could not take minted as an argument probably because of your remark, the syntax I use for resizebox is the one I use when I resize tabulars \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{\begin{minted} ... \end{minted}}

Comment: Exactly minipage argument is `{}` not `[]` as you put in the question. (And it would not be ignored), but as your question implied you used it with `[]` then errors would be expected.  never resize tabulars, it will never give a good outcome.

Comment: Thank for your comment I will edit my answer. However it is "ignored" still in the sense where the long coding line goes over the limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the option `breaklines` to a `minted` environment, or set the option globally with `\setminted{breaklines}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not really necessary since 2018

\usepackage{minted}
\setminted[python]{breaklines}

\begin{document}
\begin{listing}
% or \begin{minted}[breaklines]{python} if you need/want it only once
\begin{minted}{python} 
from foo import Foo, Fuzz, Whizz, Buzz, Bar, Baz, Fee, Fie, Foe, Foo, Foobar, WhizzBuzz, LongBar, FieFoe, FeeFie, FooFuzz
a = Foo()
b = Bar()
c = a + b
print(c)
\end{minted}
\caption{Code example}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very elegant solution ! Thank you very much !
So it is basically the only way to make it work ?

Comment: @jeandut No idea. Never used `minted` in my life `;-)`

Answer (score 2):

Campa's answer is far better, but if you really don't want to break lines,  you can make the font smaller than `\tiny` like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{minted}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{listing}
\begin{minted}[fontsize={\fontsize{5.5}{6.5}\selectfont}]{python}
from foo import Foo, Fuzz, Whizz, Buzz, Bar, Baz, Fee, Fie, Foe, Foo, Foobar, WhizzBuzz, LongBar, FieFoe, FeeFie, FooFuzz
a = Foo()
b = Bar()
c = a + b
print(c)
\end{minted}
\caption{Code example}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

(The first number after `\fontsize` sets the font size; the second the spacing between lines.)

[image: tiny tiny minted]
But that's unreadable. Please don't do that.

Comment: Thank you for this answer did not know it was so easy to go below tiny in terms of fontsizes.

Comment: But this is not *parametric*, isn't it ? If I change my margin later on its wont fit anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You can resize the `minted` environment, but you'll get really tiny glyphs, which are probably unhelpful to the reader.

However, the following solution could be satisfying when the overshoot is not very large. Otherwise, breaking lines as indicated by [campa](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/644823/4427) is a better strategy.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsavebox{\mintedbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{listing}

\begin{lrbox}{\mintedbox}
% coerce minted to produce a box, rather than a full width environment
\RecustomVerbatimEnvironment{Verbatim}{BVerbatim}{}
\begin{minted}{python}
from foo import Foo, Fuzz, Whizz, Buzz, Bar, Baz, Fee, Fie, Foe, Foo, Foobar, WhizzBuzz, LongBar, FieFoe, FeeFie, FooFuzz
a = Foo()
b = Bar()
c = a + b
print(c)
\end{minted}
\end{lrbox}

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\usebox{\mintedbox}}

\caption{Code example}

\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

The trick is that `minted` uses internally `Verbatim` from the `fancyvrb` package and one can locally recustom it to be `BVerbatim` (see the documentation of `fancyvrb` to know the difference).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this answer ! This is less cool than Campa's answer as you said but it's closer to what I originally asked for.